# How to show customer Email in email template?

Tags: prestashop-1.6

I am trying to show customer Email in email template that usually Prestashop send after a order was placed, so I tried to add it like this variable:

```
{email}
```

but when email is delivered it shows inside the email like {email}

So how can it be done? I noticed that all variables in email templates are inserted like this:

```
{history_url}
{order_name}
{firstname} 
{lastname}
```

I also checked the file mailalerts.php and AdminOrderController.php but I cant make it work, maybe there is some other files I must look in, who knows?

Answer (score 0):

The variable you mention, `email`, seems to be defined for Smarty to use with email templates. Maybe you are editing the wrong file. Email templates are stored at:

```
<path to Prestashop>/themes/<your theme>/mails/<language>
```

Where `<language>` is a two letter name like `en`. The particular file for order confirmations should be called `order_conf.html`. Are you editing this file?